# TSQL works in query analyzer but fails as a job step

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a multi step job that has worked fine for months.  All of the sudden it is failing on step 5.  If I run the tsql for step 5 in query analyzer it works just fine.  Any thoughts?  Below is the code I am using.

```
MERGE BISS..tblBoxInfo AS target
USING ( SELECT BX.BOX_BOXNO, BX.BOX_UDF_AIRR_BOXNO, CONVERT(VARCHAR(510), BX.BOX_DESC), 
            --RTRIM(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(510),BOX_DESC), 1, 
PATINDEX(N'%[^' + CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32) + N']%', BOX_DESC)-1, N' '))
            BX.BOX_UDF_NARA_LOCATION, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DP.DEPT_ID), 
            DP.DEPT_NAME, BX.BOX_UBN, BX.BOX_RCID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),CLV.CLV_TITLE), 
            BX.BOX_DT_CREATION,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), BX.BOX_UDF_TRIBES),--was NOS = CASE BOX_SROOM_INDEX WHEN 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            BX.BOX_DT_FROM, BX.BOX_DT_TO, SS.SROOM_ID
      FROM ISTAbq3Ver01.VssEnt.dbo.BOXES BX
        LEFT JOIN ISTAbq3Ver01.VssEnt.dbo.DEPTS DP
            ON DP.DEPT_ID_FULL = BX.BOX_DEPT
        LEFT JOIN ISTAbq3Ver01.VssEnt.dbo.SROOMS SS
            ON SS.SROOM_AUTO_INDEX = BX.BOX_SROOM_INDEX
        LEFT JOIN ISTAbq3Ver01.VssEnt.dbo.CUSTOM_LISTS_VALUES CLV
            ON CLV.CLV_AUTO_INDEX = BX.BOX_UDF_AIRR_WORKSITE
      WHERE NOT ( SS.SROOM_ID IN (
                        N'MP',
                        N'INDEX',
                        N'QC1',
                        N'QC2',
                        N'NTEMP',
                        N'SF135',
                        N'SFPREP',
                        N'NOS',
                        N'RR',
                        N'NTEMP2',
                        N'OHTA',
                        N'DUPS 36',
                        N'RSH',
                        N'DISC',
                        N'NARAT',
                        N'TRANS',
                        N'ABQ')
                     OR SS.SROOM_ID LIKE N'PGRS-%')
     --WHERE SS.SROOM_ID IN (N'NOS', N'NARA') 
    --  OR SS.SROOM_ID LIKE 'SL%'
    /*ORDER BY BOX_BOXNO */) AS source 
(BoxID,BoxNum,BoxTitle,BoxLocation,BoxSourceCode,BoxSource,OST,FRC,WorkSite,dtLoaded,TribeInfo,dtFrom,dtTo, BoxStatus)
ON (target.BoxID = source.BoxID)
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.BoxNumber != source.BoxNum
            OR target.BoxTitle != source.BoxTitle
            OR target.BoxLocation != source.BoxLocation 
            OR target.BoxSourceCode != source.BoxSourceCode
            OR target.BoxSource != source.BoxSource
            OR target.OSTNumber != source.OST
            OR target.FRCNumber != source.FRC
            OR target.WorkSite != source.WorkSite
            OR target.LoadedDate != source.dtLoaded
            OR target.TribeInfo != source.TribeInfo
            OR target.From_Date != source.dtFrom
            OR target.To_Date != source.dtTo 
            OR target.BoxStatus != source.BoxStatus )
THEN UPDATE SET BoxNumber = source.BoxNum,
            BoxTitle = source.BoxTitle,
            BoxLocation = source.BoxLocation,
            BoxSourceCode = source.BoxSourceCode,
            BoxSource = source.BoxSource,
            OSTNumber = source.OST,
            FRCNumber = source.FRC,
            WorkSite = source.WorkSite,
            LoadedDate = source.dtLoaded,
            TribeInfo = source.TribeInfo,
            From_Date = source.dtFrom,
            To_Date = source.dtTo,
            BoxStatus = source.BoxStatus
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (BoxID,BoxNumber,BoxTitle,BoxLocation,
        BoxSourceCode,BoxSource,OSTNumber,FRCNumber,
        WorkSite,LoadedDate,TribeInfo,From_Date,To_Date, BoxStatus)
VALUES (source.BoxID,source.BoxNum,source.BoxTitle,source.BoxLocation,
        source.BoxSourceCode,source.BoxSource,source.OST,source.FRC,
        source.WorkSite,source.dtLoaded,source.TribeInfo,source.dtFrom,source.dtTo, BoxStatus)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE;
--OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.*, GETDATE() INTO BISS_Historical..LogTblBoxInfo;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: The following error is in the Log File: Message
Executed as user: IST\sqlsvr. MERGE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1934).  The step failed.

Comment: Have you tried adding SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON (or OFF) in the job step before the query?

Comment: No, I haven't but I'll try that now and see what happens.

Comment: Well, that seems to have been the solution.  The job takes several hours to run but it has passed the step where it was initially failing.  Thank you!  Any idea as to why this would need to be added to a job step where it would not be necessary in query analyzer?  Also this job ran for months without adding this.

Comment: I would say someone changed the setting on the database which is what the job would use. SSMS has a setting for that which might be overriding the database settings.